# How do i add a standard account to sudoers file, or give that standard account root privileges?

Tags: permissions, sudo, root

I am new and i wonder how am i supposed to run some commands in my standard account (since i don't want to harm system files) that needs root privileges.

i have used sudo and it prompted me to enter the current user's password which is not root, guide me to a way to to it safe.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the account the system created for you during the installation process, then you are already a member of the `sudo` group and you will be able to use root priviledges whenever you use `sudo` with your own password.

In any other case, just add your user to the `sudo` and `adm` groups.

Comment: The `adm` group, IIRC, is just useful for reading some logs.

Comment: This.  The need to use sudo is mainly prevent accidentally entering a command that can harm the system.  It's not (on a single user system) intended to prevent the standard user from doing (almost) anything, it's just to remind you to think before you proceed.

Comment: I added a user under standard type, i want to give it permission to run sudo command, how am i supposed to do this?

Comment: Log on as a user who already has root rights and type `sudo gpasswd -a new_user_name sudo` and `sudo gpasswd -a new_user_name adm`.